# How to specify scope in C?

Tags: c, variables, scope

Is it possible to specify the scope in C?

```
int x = 5;

void setX(int x) {
    (this, self, etc).x = x;
}
```

I know that there cannot be a `this` or `self` in C because it is not an object. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `this` or `self` does not affect scope. The equivalent in C would be a `struct` object, which also has *members* (in the example `.x` represents a *member* while `x` represents a *variable*). Scope is controlled through certain syntax constructs -- pretty much everywhere braces (`{}`) are encountered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `extern` to access the global variable like such:

```
int a = 10;

int foo(int a)
{
    int b;
    {
        extern int a;
        b = a;
    }
    //b now contains the value 10
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The way this is usually done is to "emulate" OO by giving the function as an additional argument a pointer to some kind of context:

```
struct state {
  int x;
}

void setX(struct state *ctx, int x) {
  ctx->x = x;
}

/* later ... */
struct state ctx;
setX(&ctx, 5);
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that you rather want to force your compiler to explicitly assign to the global variable instead of the local argument. Well, this is not possible, but the above example shows how you could achieve something similar to what you're maybe used to from other programming languages. Even in C, using global variables is not necessarily a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

Well in your example, you just cannot. The file scope object `x` is hidden by the block scope object `x` and you cannot access the file scope object `x` directly (i.e., I mean without using some pointers to the  file scope `x`).

> (C99, 6.2.1p4) "If an identifier designates two different entities in the same name
>   space, the scopes might overlap. If so, the scope of one entity (the inner scope) will be a
>   strict subset of the scope of the other entity (the outer scope). Within the inner scope, the
>   identifier designates the entity declared in the inner scope; **the entity declared in the outer scope is hidden (and not visible) within the inner scope.**"

**EDIT**: See [@howardh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559098/how-to-specify-scope-in-c/9559225#9559225) answer, without using pointers it is possible to refer to the file scope object in the inner scope with use of the `extern` specifier.

From The New C Standard by Derek M. Jones:

> "It is possible to refer to objects in disjoint scopes by using pointers to them. It is also possible, through use of linkage, for an identifier denoting an object at file scope to be visible within a nested block scope even though there is another declaration of the same identifier in an intervening scope."

```
extern int glob;

void f1(void)
{
    int glob = 0;
    {
        extern int glob; /* Refers to same object as file scope glob. */
        glob++;
    }
    /* Visible glob still has value 0 here. */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with some pointer-mangling & macros:

```
int x;

#define setX(val) _actualSetX(&x, val);

void _actualSetX(int *xPtr, int x)
{
    *xPtr = x;
}
```